# Why does someone downvote my question in less than five seconds?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, downvote-reason

Sometimes when I ask a question, as soon as I press *Post Your Question*, someone downvotes my question in less than five seconds. Why?

Please just read the question first, then after 10 seconds I will be happy with your downvote.

Comment: It takes less than five seconds to read your [most recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30639762/is-android-m-mnc-preview-is-independent-api-or-just-update-for-last-api-22).

Comment: People's downvotes are not based on whether you're happy with their timing. It does not take a long time to gauge whether a question is of adequate quality or not.

Comment: you are very fast my friend

Comment: Far less than that to read the title and decide, "you know, this really isn't clear." I'm not really familiar with Android so I can't say whether it's understandable with effort -- but it should not be difficult to read a question title.

Comment: To the Android experts - is there a valid question behind the question linked by TZHX above? If there is, consider editing it to make it clearer. This may be a case where the language barrier is the main issue. (It may also be simply a bad question, though, no matter how you edit it.)

Comment: I think even  Android experts or other Experts need at least 10 s to decide is this question Good Or Not

Comment: @Maheer  - not really. I wouldn't get hung up on how quickly people vote.

Comment: I read a lot of questions in a day. It's not always even necessary to get to the end of the title before I know it's a bad one (in this case, *"Why does someone downvote"* was sufficient)!

Comment: @jonrsharpe  no my friend its not sufficient ,, because I dont ask  Why does someone downvote ,, I ask Why does someone downvote without understand the entire question

Comment: and this is different Question

Comment: `Why does someone downvote without understand the entire question` we will never know. Neither will you. Let it go. Concentrate on what you *can* do instead.

Comment: I am a speed reader  -I read your question here in 6 seconds (slow night for me), and then read it again (5 seconds) and then, decided to downvote

Comment: Yes, it is sufficient, because any individual can only ever speak to their own downvotes. They are anonymous, and no explanation is required. Maybe [TIm lost his keys](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215397/248731). And the reset of it (*"without understand the entire question"*) is your assumption - why do you think they don't?

Comment: Probably the question is really of bad quality? Any way, it is better to concentrate of improving questions then on calculating time between posting and downvoting...

Comment: It took me less than a second, from your title alone, to understand this and downvote.

Comment: This is sad typical s.o. (or actually general s.e.) behavior when a question, unlike maybe the author‘s, is very specific and by that occasionally very long, then the voter can only have had the title or first sentence as reference and when this is not badly formulated and the question has not been asked before, then it is an entirely legit question, nonetheless i’ve seen the described situation many times already, and i‘m not even on s.o. for thaaat long. **So i would say:  same old problem, which is a real pity given what s.e. is made for.**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firstly: I'm not a domain expert, but I think your question - essentially asking "what is new in (insert API here)?" - is not on topic on Stack Overflow. It might work in the Android chat room, but I don't think it has a place on SO proper.

Apart from that, Stack Overflow tends to be harsh towards questions with syntax issues. Many posts written by non-native speakers of English have some of those. That's unfair, but SO gets many thousands of new questions a day and the community is quick to judge what comes in, for better or worse.

Looking [at your last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30639762/is-android-m-mnc-preview-is-independent-api-or-just-update-for-last-api-22), now deleted, that probably triggered your questions, it's possible someone just downvoted it without trying to parse its content, but there's nothing you or we can do about that.

For future questions, there are a couple of small things you can do to make your post look better:

- Be on topic (obviously)
- Be careful to always use proper punctuation and capitalization.

  - Put a period behind each sentence.
  - Be consistent with capitalization (Always say `API`).
- Make your questions longer than just a sentence or two.

Comment: I don't worry about the punctuation and grammar, these can be edited if necessary - I vote only on quality

Comment: @santiago that's a great attitude to have. It may not be everyone's, though - making a post look good from the start is important.

Comment: Oh yes, that is very true - first impressions do count

Comment: Well yes but ‚more than 2 sentences‘ has really no part in the quality of every question!